# Slicing multiple CSV files at once

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, csv

I'm currently reading in 5 CSV files and looking to get a particular column of data for a different variables

I am doing that with Pandas read_csv, and then trying to slice that variable

```
all_files = pd.read_csv('ca.csv'), pd.read_csv("ny.csv"), pd.read_csv("tn.csv"), pd.read_csv('az.csv'), pd.read_csv("tx.csv')

date_index = all_files[1:, 1]
```

This throws up error **TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple**

Not sure where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: You're not slicing properly. At least remove the comma `all_files[1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is that`all_files` is a tuple of several dataframes, one from each file that you read. So when you try to do `all_files[slice]` you're slicing the *tuple*, and not the dataframes it contains. Tuples can only be sliced using integers, just like a plain list, hence the error.

If you want to get the same column from each of the dataframes, you need some loop structure:

```
date_indexes = [df.ix[:,0] for df in all_files]
```

The above code for example will get you the 1st column from each of the dataframes you read, as a series, in a list.

If your intention is to combine the dataframes in some way after you read them, you might not need this. You could instead look into [stacking](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) them. Stacking also works on pandas series (which is what the extracted columns from the dataframes are), if what you want is to get a long sequence by combining the same column from each file.

Comment: That's a great explanation, thankyou! Was starting to wonder if I needed a loop to properly dig into the files. That explains it